# how to do sql query check if empty without useing php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In this SQL query I select by id was set in the session but at some cases there is no found any id match the field in the table, so I put `if/else` statement with `mysql_num_rows` function to avoid error message...

So my question is: Is thre any SQL code to check if is there is value or not without using `mysql_num_rows` function?

```
SELECT *
     , d_articles.ar_id
     , d_articles.ar_article_title
     , d_articles.ar_article_desc
     , d_articles.ar_created
     , d_articles.ar_link_img
     , d_articles.ar_img
FROM
     d_articles
WHERE
     d_articles.ar_hide = 1 AND 
     d_articles.ar_category_id ='" . $this->session->userdata('branch_id') . "'
ORDER BY 
    ar_created desc limit 1
```

Comment: What would you want to happen if there is no such record?

Comment: show the entire code, along with php.

Comment: @user1673473 But you need a some sort of query to retrieve the information whether there is such a record or not.

Comment: ok i know..but know i ask if any solution to avoid error message if empty value

Comment: @user1673473 You will always have to have some checks as your query can have two states: no record or one record. Just like you use `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` for multiple records you could use `if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` for a single record. `mysql_fetch_array` returns `false` for when there is no next record to be fetched an the `if` condition fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

FOR SQL QUERY:

```
$tsql = "SELECT ProductID, Name, Color, Size, ListPrice

           FROM Production.Product

           WHERE Name LIKE '%' + ? + '%' AND ListPrice > 0.0";

  $params = array( $_REQUEST['query'] );

  $getProducts = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql, $params);

  if ( $getProducts === false)

        { die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) ); }
```

[READ MORE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: @user1673473 Your using PHP & SQL?